# How to apply DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer to all queries in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join

When executing queries with eager loading some one-to-many associations i'm always using DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer (to not to have duplicated *Video* entries in a result list) like:

```
var video = session.QueryOver<Video>().Where(x => x.Id == 146)
                    .Fetch(x => x.Genres).Eager
                    .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                    .List();
```

Is there a way to apply this globally to all the queries, at the ISessionFactory configuration time?
Cause in most cases I certainly want it to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

You could do that in a base repository class.